# Taking over a Magento site, old developer added a 'newest' sort by feature for categories, where to look for code?

Tags: magento-1.9, category, extensions, sorting

Pretty new to Magento.

The old dev added a sort by feature for 'newest', however, whatever he did locks sorting to 'newest' on all categories and I need to either remove or change it. It does not appear to be an extension, where is a good place to start looking for the code he may have added?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`grep` is your best friend. 
http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ugrep.htm

What I usually do, is inspect the block with Firebug to spot any distinctive class or ID, and then I just grep it.

You can also use Template Path Hints, but it won't really help you if he put code into Block classes. http://help.sweettoothrewards.com/article/434-how-do-i-turn-on-template-path-hints

Comment: Just adding you can add block classes to the template hints

Answer (score 2):

The "locked" sorting sounds to me that either he has overridden the file of the product lists; then look into `app/code/local`, if there is a `Mage/` folder look into `Mage/Catalog/` ans inspect the differences of these files with the files in the `app/code/core` folder.

Another possibility is that he has overridden a class using an extension. There are several tools that can help you find these. I prefer [n98-magerun](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun) and [FireGento_Debug](https://github.com/firegento/firegento-debug) (both having a ton of other useful features).

Comment: Addendum: A default -relatively old- magento file structure should look like this: http://doc-magento.com/nav.html?_functions/index.html
app/code/local/Mage is a very easy way to override app/code/core/Mage